# How to map the array key value parameters using SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have an Array  which will be dynamically created and it's as follows.

```
val arrayKeyValueParams ="parameters": [
              {
                "key": "clrId",
                "value": "Test8"
              },
              {
                "key": "hSId",
                "value": "0001xyz"
              }
]
```

I want to pass these key values as in below format using scala.

```
"base_parameters": {
          "clrId": "Test8",
          "hSId": "0001xyz"
        }
```

I have class which I created and pass these parameters as mapped parameters. The below class MAP is from `scala.Predef`.

```
case class ntask(@JsonProperty("base_parameters") parameters:Map[String, String])
```

So Now I want to pass the values to the above class.

```
val arrays=arrayKeyValueParams
var map:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]=scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]
for(a <- arrays)
{
  map += (a.key->a.value.asInstanceOf[String])
}
val nbtask= ntask.apply(keyValueParamsmap)
```

I'm getting the following error .

```
found   : mutable.Map[String,String]
 required: Map(String, String)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mutable.Map` and `immutable.Map` are different types, so you just can't assign one to the other which is what your code appears to be trying to do.

But there is a lot of confusion over `var`/`val` and `mutable`/`immutable` in this code so I suggest going back to a basic course on Scala, or at very least providing some valid Scala code which shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I have corrected the above post by assigning the same type. The issue where I was getting is here.    val nbtask= ntask.apply(keyValueParamsmap)